# Classification of genus 1 Lefschetz fibration over a disk with 6 singular fibers

Tags: reference-request, sg.symplectic-geometry, mapping-class-groups, 4-manifolds, elliptic-surfaces

For a genus 1 Lefschetz fibration over a sphere, there is a good classification in B. Moishezon, Complex surfaces and connected sums of complex projective planes. In this case, the number $K$ of irreducible singular fibers is divided by 12 and the total manifold is the elliptic surface $E(k/12)$.

Suppose $X\to D$ is a genus 1 Lefschetz fibration over a disk with 6 singular fibers. Suppose further $\partial X$ is the mapping torus with monodromy $-Id$. Then is there any classification (up to diffeomorphism) of $X$? I guess $X$ is always the "half" of $E(1)\cong \mathbb{C}P^2\#9\overline{\mathbb{C}P^2}$.